# Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI

Tags: ethereum, binance, cryptocurrency, remix

I deployed a contract of a token that has up to nine other files imported to the finance blockchain. I have done everything I can read and try in order to verify it. But it keeps giving me error.
Compiler debug log:
Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI
Found the following ContractName(s) in source code : Address, Context, IERC20, IUniswapV2Factory, IUniswapV2Pair, IUniswapV2Router01, IUniswapV2Router02, Ownable, RentCoin, SafeMath
But we were unable to locate a matching bytecode (err_code_2)
For troubleshooting, you can try compiling your source code with the Remix - Solidity IDE and check for exceptions

My contract was compiled and deployed using Remix and optimization was set to 200. My compiler version is 0.6.12 and the link to the flattened contract is below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/100J73q4hutqqmT1tZEuMn46YYFmzYaT0/view?usp=sharing

I understand that this contract involves constructors but I really need a practical guide on how to locate them and convert them to the right-abi-encoded JSON format that the verification page may accept.